# Pandas Group By and Conditional Ratio

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to take the ratio of counts based on a condition and I'm struggling to get it right using `pandas` data frame.

The data is as below:

```
                   JOB_ROLE           COMMENTS ACTIVITY_TYPE  COUNTS  
             Director-Level  Meeting Requested     EmailSend     490    
              Manager-Level  Meeting Requested     EmailSend     305  
             Non-Managerial  Meeting Requested     EmailSend     272  
     Top Executive; C-Level  Meeting Requested     EmailSend     226  
                   VP-Level  Meeting Requested     EmailSend     185
             Director-Level  Meeting Requested    FormSubmit     131
              Manager-Level  Meeting Requested    FormSubmit      74
     Top Executive; C-Level  Meeting Requested    FormSubmit      61
                   VP-Level  Meeting Requested    FormSubmit      53
             Non-Managerial  Meeting Requested    FormSubmit      52
                      Other  Meeting Requested     EmailSend      20
                      Other  Meeting Requested    FormSubmit       2
```

My attempt is as below:

```
ratios =  mr_jr.groupby('JOB_ROLE').apply(lambda x: x[x['ACTIVITY_TYPE']=='FormSubmit'].COUNTS / x[x['ACTIVITY_TYPE']=='EmailSend'].COUNTS)
```

What is the right way to apply the condition to each group and perform arithmetic?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDITED**

*Desired Output:*

```
print(list(ratios)) # prints: [0.26, 0.24, 0.19, 0.27, 0.28, 0.1]
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @ScottBoston: Sorry, edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a job for a pivot table.

`piv = df.pivot('JOB_ROLE', 'ACTIVITY_TYPE').COUNTS`

Output:

```
In [119]: piv.FormSubmit / piv.EmailSend
Out[119]: 
JOB_ROLE
Director-Level            0.267347
Manager-Level             0.242623
Non-Managerial            0.191176
Other                     0.100000
Top Executive; C-Level    0.269912
VP-Level                  0.286486
dtype: float64
```

Without pivot:

```
df.set_index('JOB_ROLE', drop=True, inplace=True)
emails = df[df.ACTIVITY_TYPE == 'EmailSend']
forms  = df[df.ACTIVITY_TYPE == 'FormSubmit']
print(forms.COUNTS / emails.COUNTS)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a cool trick. Is there a way to do it without `pivot`, perhaps using `groupby` and `apply`

Comment: Probably. Although if each (job_role, activity_type) pair occurs only once, groupby is likely not needed.

Comment: Yea. Actually, the sample data I posted is the result of a `groupby` that is the reason, you can only see one row per pair. Thank you for your help.